# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Nor967.jpg'

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, python-3.x, data-augmentation

Whenever I try to use the data augmentation ImageDataGenerator I'm getting an error like could not convert string to float. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pathlib import Path

jpeg_images = 
list(Path(r'D:\covid_deep_learning\train\train').glob('**/*.jpg'))
np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(str(file))).flatten() for file in jpeg_images])
folder = ['COVID19_AND_PNEUMONIA','NORMAL']
Path = r'D:\covid_deep_learning\train\train'
for i in range(2):
    listing = os.listdir(Path+'/'+folder[i])
    for file in listing :
        img = cv2.imread(Path+'/'+folder[i]+'/'+file)
        resize=cv2.resize(img,(70,70))
        cv2.imwrite(Path+'/'+folder[i]+'/'+file,resize)
        cv2.imshow('resize', img)
        plt.imshow(resize)
    print(listing)
    print(len(listing))
def load_images(path, df):
    train_image = []
    for i in tqdm(range(df.shape[0])):
        try:



            train_image.append(resize)
        except OSError:
            print(df['id'][i])
    image_array = np.array(train_image)   
    return image_array


train_image_path = r'D:\covid_deep_learning\train\train/'
test_image_path  = r'D:\covid_deep_learning\test/'

X = load_images(train_image_path,train)
test_images = load_images(test_image_path, test)

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test_class = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)
 y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train)
 y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test_class)
 model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",  activation='relu',input_shape=(70,70,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same", activation='relu' ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same", activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same", activation='relu' ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same", activation='relu' ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.50))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
opt = SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-3 / 25)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

datagen.fit(X_train)
print('augmentation')
```

### After data augmentation I'm getting an error like this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-f6bc9e2818e8> in <module>
     11         fill_mode='nearest')
     12 
 ---> 13 datagen.fit(X_train)
     14 print('augmentation')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py in fit(self, x, augment, rounds, seed)
    924             seed: Int (default: None). Random seed.
    925        """
--> 926         x = np.asarray(x, dtype=self.dtype)
    927         if x.ndim != 4:
    928             raise ValueError('Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. '

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NORMAL2-IM-0340-0001.jpeg'
```

Comment: in your first line of code you use a variable `X`. Can you edit your questions and show how you created `X`?

Comment: yeah I've edited

Comment: still some code is missing. In `X = load_images(train_image_path,train)`, what is the  `train` variable? In the function `load_images` you start using a variable `resize` without defining it.